# How to find max and min with parse.com cloud parsing?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have a function in parse cloud that counts average price. Also I need to find max and min price. Have no clue how to do that.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("averagePrice", function(request, response) {
var query = new Parse.Query("cars_new");
query.equalTo("make", request.params.make);
query.equalTo("model", request.params.model);
query.equalTo("year", request.params.year);
query.find({
success: function(results) {
  console.log(results.length);
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    sum += parseInt(results[i].get("price").replace(/\s+/g, ''), 10);
  }
  response.success(sum / results.length);
},
error: function () {
  // body...
  response.error("no match");
  console.log("error");
}


});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Parse.Cloud.define("maxPrice", function(request, response) {
var query = new Parse.Query("cars_new");
query.equalTo("make", request.params.make);
query.equalTo("model", request.params.model);
query.equalTo("year", request.params.year);
query.find({
success: function(results) {
  var max = -Infinity;
  var price;
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    price = parseInt(results[i].get("price").replace(/\s+/g, ''), 10);
    if(price > max) max = price;
  }
  response.success(max);
},
error: function () {
  // body...
  response.error("no match");
  console.log("error");
}


});
});

Parse.Cloud.define("minPrice", function(request, response) {
var query = new Parse.Query("cars_new");
query.equalTo("make", request.params.make);
query.equalTo("model", request.params.model);
query.equalTo("year", request.params.year);
query.find({
success: function(results) {
  var min = Infinity;
  var price;
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    price = parseInt(results[i].get("price").replace(/\s+/g, ''), 10);
    if(price < min) min = price;
  }
  response.success(min);
},
error: function () {
  // body...
  response.error("no match");
  console.log("error");
}


});
});
```